# what are the minimum files needed to compile an android project from scratch?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I have an android project with me which I have compiled and run multiple ties on my machine. I need to send to whole project to some else who wants to edit and compile the code for themselves. But I think since I have already compiled the code the workspace's folder has files that were generated by my compile which will be unnecessary for them. So which files can I delete, so that they will get just the minimum required files so that they will be able to compile it in their computer? I want to do this so that I can reduce the size of the email attachment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the /bin and /gen folder. This is created during compilation. It will reduce the size of your project.

Answer (score 1):

just remove your bin and gen folder...zip it  and mail to your friend.:)